# NavigationExperimental: Why does renderScene() run 3 times and not once?

Tags: react-native

While I was testing out and tried to understand how `NavigationCompositionExample` works, I found that `renderScene()` was called 3 times (exactly how many tabs are).  Why?  Shouldn't it be called once with the right index.

```
class ExampleMainView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationView
        navigationState={this.props.navigationState}
        style={styles.tabsContent}
        renderScene={(tabState, index) => {
          console.log('index:', index);  // <<<<< This is printed 3x.
          return (
            <ExampleTabScreen
              key={tabState.key}
              navigationState={tabState}
              onNavigate={this._handleNavigation.bind(this, tabState.key)}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  //...
}
```

The output:

```
'index:', 0
'index:', 1
'index:', 2
```